# Counting GameObjects inside parent in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to know the count of how many objects are inside my parent GameObject.

Quick answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [transform.childCount](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-childCount.html) on your parent gameObject script.

Example code:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Example() {
        print(transform.childCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as i posted the question, i did it as well (with same variable). Still Thanks. :)

Comment: I am facing another issue. I have to holes in my Scene. And when ball enters one it comes out of second. I have used onTriggerEnter But the ball keeps on coming in and out from both holes in a loop. How to fix it..?

Comment: That question is irrelevant to this one. In Stack Overflow you should keep posts in topic for others to benefit from it. I suggest you post another question for that.

Comment: But my limit of posting question is over. thats what i posted it here. I don't know why... :(

Comment: You have less than 125 reputations, which means that you can only post questions every 20 minutes. That's the rule of Stack Overflow - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask. Try posting your question now, should work.

Comment: No it says you have posted question that got less attention + lack of quality material. :(